# SQL count if not blank

Tags: sql-server

I have to count how many times in a month someone rents a bike(just an example) and how many times a bike is returned for that month. In the table of data I was given in excel, there should be only one bike returned for the month, although it counts 10(I have ten rows of user data). The problem is these blanks are counted and are not registered as a NULL value or a ' ' value so those will not work in a case statement. How count I format a case to count where there is an actual date format value present?
This is kinda the gist of what I have so far(I know the case statement is wrong its just an idea of what i am trying to do).

```
SELECT
DISTINCT MONTH(createddate) AS [Month], 
COUNT(createddate) AS [Renters],
COUNT(CASE WHEN (datereturned) = DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [Returns])
FROM Bikes WHERE datereturned IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(createddate);
```

---

It will return each month correctly in the table and I can get the number of renters each month correct, but returns is wrong. This is what is SHOULD return :

Month | 4 | 5 ---
Renters  |  5      |   5 ---
Returns  |  0      |   1

This is what I return(INCORRECT):

Month | 4 | 5 ---
Renters  |  5      |   5 ---
Returns  |  5      |   5

Answer (score 1):

use sum instead of count

```
SELECT
 MONTH(createddate) AS [Month], 
COUNT(createddate) AS [Renters],
sum(CASE WHEN (datereturned) = DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [Returns])
FROM Bikes WHERE datereturned IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(createddate);
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` doesn't count the number of non-zero values, it counts the number of non-null values.

So to get count of rows where some `expr` is true, you can use `COUNT` or `SUM`. The following all produce the same result:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN expr THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
COUNT(CASE WHEN expr THEN 1 END)
SUM(CASE WHEN expr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

The `SUM` variant is usually chosen, because it doesn't rely on special null handling, which often confuses people.

---

*FYI:* Since `GROUP BY MONTH(createddate)` ensures that every row has a different value, the `DISTINCT` is meaningless, and just slows down your query. Remove it.

---

> how many times a bike is returned for that month

First, your query only counts bikes that had been returned (`WHERE datereturned IS NOT NULL`). What about recently rented bikes that hasn't been returned.

I'm not sure what `(datereturned) = DATE` is supposed to test, but the way you phrased it makes it unclear whether a bike that is rented in July and returned in August should count the return in July or August.

If you count it in July, and only include returned bikes in the query, then `Returns` will always be the same as `Renters`, so I'll assume that it needs to be counted for `August`.

That means your query needs to see the row twice, once to be counted in the month when it was rented, and once to be counted in the month when it was returned. For that, you need to `UNION ALL`, and do the `GROUP BY` *after* the union:

```
SELECT [Month]
     , SUM([Renters]) AS [Renters]
     , SUM([Returns]) AS [Returns]
  FROM (
         SELECT MONTH(createddate) AS [Month]
              , 1 AS [Renters]
              , 0 AS [Returns]
           FROM Bikes
             -- no WHERE because we want to count non-returned bikes
         UNION ALL
         SELECT MONTH(datereturned) AS [Month]
              , 0 AS [Renters]
              , 1 AS [Returns]
           FROM Bikes
          WHERE datereturned IS NOT NULL -- Only count returned bikes
       ) x
 GROUP BY [Month]
 ORDER BY [Month]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you just need to use the minimum date as start point on comparing dates. This would skip all NULLs and any other value that is not an actual date.

So, the change you need to do is to replace `IS NOT NULL` to any date to start with. For instance, this is what I have changed :

```
WHERE datereturned > '1753-01-01'
```

You can see I have replaced IS NOT NULL with `'1753-01-01'`, which is the minimum default date in SQL Server. Another thing on your CASE, if you used my method, then you don't need the case. You only need DISTINCT count for both `createddate` AND `datereturned` so your finalized query should something similar to this :

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(createddate) AS [Month], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT createddate)   AS [Renters], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT datereturned)  AS [Returns]
FROM 
    Bikes 
WHERE 
    datereturned > '1753-01-01'
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(createddate)
```